# What is the difference between a remote user and a local user on a server?

Tags: ubuntu

This question probably has a simple answer, but I am still confused. For example, today I was setting up `vsftpd` on my unbuntu 12.04 server and I saw the following line:

```
#Uncomment this to allow local users to log in
#local_enable=YES
```

If I am logging in from a terminal, aren't I a remote user? What is a local user that instance? Would I always be a remote user if I am accessing my remote server through a ssh session?

I'm a beginner and I really want to learn server administration.

Answer (score 3):

I admit i'm guessing here as i've not used vsftpd...

If you're looking up a username from a central place like ldap, it won't be a local user. A local user is one which is authetnicated through the local password/shadow files on the system itself.

Also, not all vsftpd users have to be 'real' users (fingers and eyeballs), they can exist purely as username/password pairs. See 'virtual' users.

Comment: Precisely. A "local" user is one whose credentials were verified through the server's ordinary user authentication process. (As opposed to anonymous users, users configured into some particular program, and so on.)

Comment: So even if I log in through a remote terminal through the password prompt, I am still considered a local user on that server?

Comment: yes. you're a local user, who'es connecting from a remote location.